# APScheduler Running 'date' early using Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, apscheduler

I am trying to use APScheduler to automate a function call. It is supposed to read a date from a website I scrape, and then at a certain time relative to that date call the function (2 minutes before). The code for this portion of the project is here:

```
for mtp, url, track in zip(mtp_num_final, url_list, race_list):

      scheduled_time = datetime.now() + relativedelta(minutes =+ (mtp - 2))

      print(scheduled_time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %I:%M%p'))

      scheduler.add_job(two_minute_scrape(url, track, 5), 'date', scheduled_time)
```

The basic gist of the above code is that race_list and and url_list hold data which the two_minute_scrape function needs. I get the amount of minutes + 2 that I want to wait from mtp num final. When I run this code, the printed out date is correct - it knows exactly when I want to run the code, but then it IMMEDIATELY runs two_minute_scrape instead of waiting for that time. Is there anyway to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekRai if I switch to `+=` then I get an illegal syntax error

Comment: `relativedelta(minutes =+ (mtp - 2))` This expression is wrong, That's why you get the syntax error. You need to read the docs. https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html

Comment: No. Switching to  `+=` gets me an illegal syntax error. If I switch to `=` it works exactly as expected. Regardless, the syntax error is not the issue. The issue is that the APScheduler knows when I want to run the program, but it runs it at an earlier time.